# T-Sql Select * Between 30% and 40%

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

#### Question

- How do I write a T-SQL Stored Procedure that lets me select percentages of rows between X% and Y%?
- So basically I would want to select the rows between 30 PERCENT and 40 PERCENT.....

I know that you can do the following, but obviously that doesn't let met specify a set of rows between 2 percentages.

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM tblAssets
```

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

```
declare @NumRecords int
SELECT @NumRecords = COUNT(*) FROM tblAssets;

With Vals As
(
SELECT tblAssets.AssetId ...
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by tblAssets.AssetId) as RN
  FROM tblAssets
)

SELECT  tblAssets.AssetId ...
FROM vals 
Where RN between 0.3*@NumRecords and 0.4*@NumRecords
```

I've updated my answer as there were 2 problems with my original answer below

1. Performance - It was beaten by the nested `TOP` solution
2. Accuracy - There is an unexpected aspect of NTILE that I was not aware of

> If the number of rows in a partition
>   is not divisible by
>   integer_expression, this will cause
>   groups of two sizes that differ by one
>   member. Larger groups come before
>   smaller groups in the order specified
>   by the OVER clause. For example if the
>   total number of rows is 53 and the
>   number of groups is five, the first
>   three groups will have 11 rows and the
>   two remaining groups will have 10 rows
>   each.

I got the following values comparing with the nested `TOP` solution.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

DECLARE @NumRecords int
SELECT @NumRecords = COUNT(*) FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values];

WITH Vals As
(
SELECT  [number]
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by [number]) as RN
  FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values]
)

SELECT [number] FROM vals Where RN
 BETWEEN 0.30*@NumRecords AND 0.40*@NumRecords
```

Gives

> Table 'spt_values'. Scan count 1,
>   logical reads 8, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table
>   'spt_values'. Scan count 1, logical
>   reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead
>   reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads
>   0.

```
SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT [number] FROM
(
SELECT TOP 40 PERCENT  [number]
FROM  [master].[dbo].[spt_values]
ORDER BY [number]  ASC
) TOP40
ORDER BY [number] DESC
```

Gives

> Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1,
>   logical reads 4726, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table
>   'spt_values'. Scan count 1, logical
>   reads 8, physical reads 0, read-ahead
>   reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
>   physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads
>   0.

**Original Answer**

```
With Vals As
(
SELECT tblAssets.AssetId ...
, NTILE (100)  OVER ( order by tblAssets.AssetId) as Pct
  FROM tblAssets 
)

SELECT * FROM vals Where Pct between 30 and 40
```

Comment: +1: Nice. I really need to learn all of the new OVER functions in SQL Server. I was thinking TOP 25 PERCENT in DESC order after TOP 40 PERCENT. NTILE looks much cleaner.

Comment: Interesting!  I was thinking the other day that NTILE is useless without the ability to define your own buckets...

Comment: @Goober - Yes. I just want to check the execution plan against Tom's suggested answer. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the syntax....I'm fairly new to T-SQl. Why have you put "..." after "SELECT tblAssets.AssetId" - PRESUME it's not syntax

Comment: @Goober - Because I never use '*' so it was just an indication to replace the ... with your actual column list!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this myself.......

```
SELECT TOP 40 *  
    INTO #TOP40
    FROM CCDtblAssets

 SELECT * FROM #TOP40
WHERE ASSETID NOT IN   
(SELECT TOP 30 ASSETID FROM #TOP40)
```

Although I do like Martins Answer.